# How to safely check arrays bounds

Tags: c#, arrays

I am making game of life in 2D array. I need to determine when all adjacent cells are empty so I just test all of them. It works well unless the cell being checked is the boundary. Then of course testing X+1 throws an exception as the index is out of the array boundaries. Can I handle this somehow instead of handling the exception?
Thanks

Comment: There are 2 forms of 2D arrays. A simple declaration would clarify this question a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want speed you'll have to treat the edge-cells differently and process the rest with a

```
for(int x = 1; x < Size-1; x++)  // these all have x-1 and x+1 neighbours
```

Answer (score 7):

use `GetLength(0)` and `GetLength(1)` to get the width and height of the array.

There is also a neat performance trick the runtime uses for its own bounds checks: casting to unsigned int to reduce the two checks into one. But since this costs readability you use it if the check is really performance critical.

```
(i >= 0) && (i < length)
```

becomes

```
(uint)i < length
```

Comment: Very neat, have just used the UINT version.

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension method for a 2D array to check if in bounds:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool In2DArrayBounds(this object[,] array, int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < array.GetLowerBound(0) ||
            x > array.GetUpperBound(0) ||
            y < array.GetLowerBound(1) ||
            y > array.GetUpperBound(1)) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, before accessing the element at index `i + 1`, check whether `i + 1` is strictly inferior to `array.Length`.

Comment: But it would need a lot of conditions then, right? y less then array, y greater, x less, x greater

Comment: It's better than catching exceptions which are for exceptional cases.